# Flutter Web - dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I was developing new Flutter Website, every time I run this command `webdev serve --auto restart` from VS Code, and test the site through http://127.0.0.1:8080/ and it just works good.

But when I did an update in **main.dart** file (normal edit for widgets), and do run the previous command again, it throws this error

> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

The terminal output is..

```
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 543ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 1.9s
[INFO] Serving `web` on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[INFO] Running build completed, took 531ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 302ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 867ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My dart file has only normal widgets.

Comment: The terminal output shows the server started correctly. Where are you seeing this error? Also check if a previously running `webdev serve --auto restart` command is terminated properly. Usually you dont have to run `webdev serve --auto restart` for every change. It does auto reload of you webpage.

Comment: It shows in the Firefox browser, while in Chrome nothing to show unless White page!. And I do really know that command will refresh or hot reload the page without run it over and over.

Comment: You can a try a `flutter clean` on the project directory. Usually this helps me from time to time when I don't see the updates I expect.

Comment: I tried it, nothing happened !